# org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [$Proxy133] to required type

Tags: java, spring

In the applicationContext.xml I have a bean `ems`:

```
<bean id="ems" class="info.ems.EMSImpl" init-method="init">
    <property name="dao" ref="dao" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
    <property name="localeList" value="${ems.locales}" />
    <property name="releaseVersion" value="${ems.version}" />
    <property name="releaseTimestamp" value="${ems.timestamp}" />
    <property name="emsHome" value="${ems.home}" />
</bean>
```

Now in applicationContext-acegi.xml I am referencing that `ems` bean:

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="info.ems.config.ProviderManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="emsImpl" ref="ems"/>        
    <property name="authenticationProvider" ref="authenticationProvider"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.acegisecurity.providers.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="ems"/>
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</bean>
```

And the ProviderManagerFactoryBean.java:

```
public class ProviderManagerFactoryBean implements FactoryBean {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private EMSImpl emsImpl;
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    public void setEmsImpl(EMSImpl emsImpl) {
        this.emsImpl = emsImpl;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

            //other code
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
19:08:56,726 INFO  [STDOUT] 2011-05-30 19:08:56,724 [ScannerThread] ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-acegi.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [$Proxy133] to required type [info.ems.EMSImpl] for property 'emsImpl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy133] to required type [info.ems.EMSImpl] for property 'emsImpl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

The EMSImpl implements EMS.

```
@Service("emsImpl")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class EMSImpl implements EMS {
     //other code
}

public interface EMS extends UserDetailsService {
     //other code
}
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Why are you not referring to your object via the interface `EMS`. That's what you *should* be doing, as far as I know.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer you suggesting me to use EMS instead of EMSImpl in the class ProviderManagerFactoryBean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Spring creates the transactional proxy object around `EMSImpl`, it makes the proxy implement the same set of interfaces at that class (i.e. `EMS`).  The proxy will not, however, be of type `EMSImpl`.

In `ProviderManagerFactoryBean`, you need to inject type type `EMS`, not `EMSImpl`. This is also good design - it decouples your classes from each other, so that they communicate via interfaces.